# Proof of the first step analysis of ruin probability: dealing with the initial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I was reading through the algebraic proof of the first step analysis of the ruin probability in the classical gambling scenario from Privault's Understanding Markov Chains.

In the proof below, I don't see how we can get (2.2.9) from the line above. We have $\{X_1 = k \pm 1\} \cap \{X_0 = k\}= \{X_1 = k \pm 1\} \cap \{X_1 - X_0 = \pm 1\}$.

But why is this probability the same as that of $P(\{X_1 = k \pm 1\} \cap \{X_1 - \tilde{X_0} = \pm 1\})$?

$X_1 - \tilde{X_0}$ is by definition just $Z$, which is independent of $X_1$ and distributed like $X_1-X_0$. So the joint distribution is just the product distribution whereas $X_0$ and $X_1$ may not be independent. How do we still get the equality in probability here?

[image]

[image]